# Importance Sampling for pricing options with longstaff and schwartz

Tags: option-pricing, monte-carlo, american-options

I have been asking this similar question before. However, I really want to be concrete and get and concrete explanation.

I have been reading the paper by [Moreni](https://www.rocq.inria.fr/mathfi/Premia/free-version/doc/premia-doc/pdf_html/Moreni_doc.pdf) and try to implement the same methodology based on least-square monte carlo for both European and American put options.
They payoff function for both these puts is given by $f(t,S_t)=\max(K-S(t),0)$. The only difference is that for American case, we have payoffs in different times from simulations depending on the optimal stopping time.

As usual we have the underlying stock price as geometric brownian motion:

$dS_t = r S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t$.

Moreni introduces the change of drift in the underlying:

$dS_t = (r+\theta\sigma )S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t$.

When simulating from the drifted process, we have to multiply the PAYOFF functions with the likelihood ratio defined as $L_\theta=\exp\{-\theta W_t+\frac{1}{2}\theta^2 t\}$

so we have $f(t,S_t)=\max(K-S(t),0)\cdot\exp\{-\theta W_t+\frac{1}{2}\theta^2 t\}$

instead of just $f(t,S_t)=\max(K-S(t),0)$

The idea is of course to use negative values for $\theta$ so we get more "in-the money paths".

But when I try to use these modified payoffs with the Longstaff and schwartz algorithm, I don't get any relevant results. The price gets extremly biased whichever value i use for $\theta$.
My question is, should the estimated continuation values in least-square method also be modified with the likelihood ratio? In that case how? Or as mentioned in the article, ONLY the payoff functions be multiplied by the likelihood ratio??

Thank you for your patience

PS* Added by request the steps that I use:

1. Generate $N$-scenarios of the drifted with $\theta$ geometric
   brownian motion
2. Save all the standard normal values $Z_t$ from the GBM for use in
   the likelihood ratio.
3. Create the likelihood ratio using the $Z_t$'s and for some value
   $\theta$
4. Use the likelihood ratio and set
   $f(t,S_t)=\max(K-S(t),0)\cdot\exp\{-\theta W_t-\frac{1}{2}\theta^2
   t\}$ for all paths
5. Now run the Least-square algorithm from $t=T$ down to $t=0$ to
   calculate all the continuation values and optimal stopping times.
6. Take average of all the scenarios.

Comment: Have you tried applying your IS scheme to the pricing of a standard European option. If so, do you observe the same behaviour?

Comment: Yes I have, and indeed I get for some values for $\theta$ a correct price with variance reduction. It is just simulating everything at time $T$...

Comment: Ok I assume that you've also checked your IS scheme when generating a full path and not simply sampling $S_T $? Longstaff-Schwartz consists in estimating the continuation value (which is a conditional expectation) using cross sectional info. IMHO you should not involve the likelihood ratio at that stage.

Comment: Also, have you checked that without IS your LS Monte Carlo works as expected (price an American put without dividend for instance?)

Comment: The LS works for ordinary case since I am using the LSM library in R.

Comment: Would it perhaps be possible for u to check out my code? I understand if it is too much of ask..

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library sorry. Do you have a description of what it does maybe? Also, could you add a description of what you are doing exactly e.g. (1) calling LSM routine to price an American option under the modified measure $\mathbb{Q}_\theta$, using $M$ paths (2) Output of LSM routine is $M$ discounted payoff values (calculated using Longstaff-Schartz algorithm). (3) Multiplying these payoff values by the likelihood ratio $L_\theta$ (4) Averaging them to get the option price under the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41141/discussion-between-elekko-and-quantuple).

Comment: I think you might have a misconception about the use of Monte Carlo Least Squares algorithm? See my answer below. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming deterministic interest rates, the price of an American call option struck at $K$ and expiring at $T$ is given by
$$ V_0 = \text{sup}_{\tau \in \mathcal{T}[0,T]} \mathbb{E}_0^\mathbb{Q}\left[ e^{-r\tau} \max(S_{\tau}-K, 0) \right] $$
where $\mathcal{T}[0,T]$ denotes a family of stopping times with values in $[0,T]$ and where, under the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$, we assume $(S_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a GBM
$$ \frac{dS_t}{S_t} = r dt + \sigma dW_t^{\mathbb{Q}} $$

Doing importance sampling boils down to computing the above price by simulating paths and computing the expectation not under the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$, but rather, under a modified measure $\mathbb{Q}^\theta$ which you have in your case chosen such that
$$ \frac{dS_t}{S_t} = (r+\sigma\theta) dt + \sigma dW_t^{\mathbb{Q}^\theta} \tag{1}$$

which implicitly shapes the Radon-Nikodym derivative (see Girsanov theorem)
$$ \left. \frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{Q}^\theta} \right\vert_{\mathcal{F}_t} =   \mathcal{E}\left(-\theta W_t^{\mathbb{Q}^\theta}\right) = \exp\left(-\theta W_t^{\mathbb{Q}^\theta} - \frac{1}{2}\theta^2 t \right) := L(\theta,t) \tag{2}$$
which defines what you refer to as the likelihood ratio.

Using a change of measure argument (+ optimal sampling theorem), one can then claim that
\begin{align}
V_0 &= \text{sup}_{\tau \in \mathcal{T}[0,T]} \mathbb{E}_0^\mathbb{Q}\left[ e^{-r\tau} \max(S_{\tau}-K, 0) \right] \\
&= \text{sup}_{\tau \in \mathcal{T}[0,T]} \mathbb{E}_0^\mathbb{Q^\theta}\left[ e^{-r\tau} \max(S_{\tau}-K, 0) L(\theta,\tau) \right]
\end{align}
where in the last equality above, $S_{\tau}$ (and the expectation) are simulated (taken) under $\mathbb{Q}^\theta$.

So what you should do is:

1. Generate $N$ stock price paths under the modified measure $\mathbb{Q}^\theta$ using the SDE (1)
2. Apply the Longstaff-Schwartz algorithm (Least Squares Monte Carlo) to obtain, for each simulated path $n=1,...,N$ the value of the discounted exercise value at the optimal stopping time $\tau^{(n)}$
   $$ e^{-r\tau^{(n)}} \max( S_{\tau^{(n)}}-K, 0 ) $$
   (under the hood, the LS algorithm identifies optimal stopping times by approximating continuation values through polynomial regressions relying on cross-sectional information and working backwards in time).
3. Once you have that, it is straightforward to compute the Monte Carlo estimator:
   \begin{align}
   V_0 &= \text{sup}_{\tau \in \mathcal{T}[0,T]} \mathbb{E}_0^\mathbb{Q^\theta}\left[ e^{-r\tau} \max(S_{\tau}-K, 0) L(\theta, \tau) \right] \\
   &\approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N  \left( e^{-r\tau^{(n)}}  \max( S_{\tau^{(n)}}-K, 0 ) \right) \times L(\theta, \tau^{(n)})
   \end{align}
   with see (2)
   $$ L(\theta,\tau^{(n)}) = \exp\left(-\theta W_{\tau^{(n)}}^{\mathbb{Q}^\theta} - \frac{1}{2}\theta^2 \tau^{(n)} \right) $$
   and by definition of a Wiener process (i.e. standard Brownian motion)
   $$ W_{\tau^{(n)}}^{\mathbb{Q}^\theta} = \sum_{ i : 0 \leq t_i \leq \tau^{(n)} } Z_i \sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_i},\ \ \ Z_i \sim N(0,1)\ \ \text{i.i.d.} $$

notice how the likelihood ratio $L(\theta,n)$ should be computed for each individual path $n=1,...,N$ depending on the optimal stopping time for that path $\tau^{(n)}$.

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify. So winer process for the likelihood function is a sum of the standard normals up to the optimal stopping time for each individual path, correct?

Comment: No Weiner process is not a sum of standard normals, it is important that the variance scales correcly. Because $\text{Var}(W_t) = t$, you should weigh the samples from your standard normals by the square root of the time step as explained in my answer. But yes, since you want to compute $L(\theta,\tau^{(n)})$ why would you go further than $\tau^{(n)}$ ??

Comment: Yes, I got it. But equation (3), I think the index on sum should go from $n=1$ to $N$ instead from $i=1$ to $N$

Comment: Note that for an American option, what you call the "payoff" can happen before maturity, due to the early exercise possibility. This is represented by $\tau^{(n)}$ and $L(\theta,\tau^{(n)})$ in the above. So when you say "we have to multiply the PAYOFF functions with the likelihood ratio", beware that this payoff does not necessarily happen at $T$.

Comment: Yes, it is, I just saw that and corrected in some seconds ago ;) Please tell me if it works now. And if the answer helped you don't hesitate to accept it. Bye.

Comment: Will let you know. Thanks alot for your help

Comment: So I implemented it and it works! Thank you! :D

Comment: @Elekko, you're welcome, glad I could help. Would you mind accepting the answer in that case? Thank you.

Comment: may I ask if the estimator is an unbiased estimator for any choice of $\theta$? I try out plotting the price ratio, $\frac{V_0^{\theta}}{V_0}$ for different choices for $\theta$, and I get it close to 1 only at very few $\theta$ values. Compared to Morenis paper, he gets the ratio to one for may choices for $\theta$. Thanks

Comment: @Elekko I don't think that it is an unbiased estimator of the true option price, essentially because LS MC already does not provide an unbiased estimator of the true American option price (the optimal stopping time rule returned by LS is sub-optimal as it suffers from foresight bias, you can reduce that and obtain a lower bound of the true option price by running 2 independent batches of simulations: 1 for calibrating the exercise boundary, 1 for pricing)   (...)

Comment: However, I don't think that it is bias that you observe here, but more probably variance. The variance of your estimator indeed significantly depends on $\theta$ (and the choice of modified measure $\mathbb{Q}^\theta$. I would advise you to run say M simulations for each individual value of $\theta$ you are willing to test, get M prices and average them before you plot the graph: $\frac{ \frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^M V_0^{\theta, m}} {V_0}$? With of course M as big as possible depending on your computational resources.

Comment: Okay, so it means that it is unnecessary to even try finding the optimal drift by solving $\nabla H(\theta)=0$, where $H(\theta)$ is the second moment of the IS-LSM estimator? I can try out running $M$ simulations and take the average of them before plotting, however that will take some time :)

Comment: Just do it 3-4 times to get a first feel of whether variance is indeed the problem. I don't understand your question "Okay, so it means (...) ?", what makes you say that? Bias and variance are two different things. It seems like solving $\nabla H(\theta) = 0$ will get you the value of $\theta$ that leads to the smallest variance estimator so why not.

Comment: Ok I understand. When checking the variance for values of $\theta$ where the ratio is close to 1, they are much less than for "the true price without drift". Thats why it for me seems that solving $\nabla H(\theta)=0$ is not necessary. I can just test many values for $\theta$, plot the graph by using M simulations and see where the variance is as lowest for fractions close to 1.

Comment: @Elekko Yes but don't forget that the function $H$ also includes a dependence on the payoff of the option you're pricing. What I mean is that maybe the conclusions you draw for a particular payoff configuration may not hold in general: solving $\nabla H(\theta) = 0$ seems like the generic way to do it. The brute force method is fine only if the type of option you're pricing will never change.

Comment: Hi again, we for this case have: $    H(\theta) = \mathbb{E}\left[ \left( f(\tau, S_{\tau}) \right)^2 \exp{\left(-2\theta W_{\tau}^{\mathbb{Q}^{\theta}} -\theta^2 \tau \right)} \right]$, and therefore $\nabla H(\theta) = \mathbb{E}\left[ (-\theta \tau-W^{\mathbb{Q}^{\theta}}) \left( f(\tau, S_{\tau}) \right)^2 \exp{\left(-2\theta W_{\tau}^{\mathbb{Q}^{\theta}} -\theta^2 \tau \right)} \right]$. How should I approximate this in a concrete way? This is needed in order to find the optimal drift, using Robbins Monro algorithm

Comment: Your gradient seems wrong to me. You have computed it as if $S_{\tau}$ and the stopping time $\tau$ did not depend on $\theta$. Plus this is not the variance but just the raw second moment, no?

Comment: It is the second moment only since that is of interest in the importance sampling case and we wish to minimize it.

Comment: Based on this article, https://www.google.se/url?q=https://quanto.inria.fr/pdf_html/Arouna_doc/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwilxZqRt9DNAhWKVSwKHW17BmIQFggPMAI&usg=AFQjCNGPyH7pslfV3fAFhuB6F1BCxMIn8Q they minimize the second moment in order to find the optimal drift. I dont really get how i should differentiate my second moment analytocally (as u stated it is wrong at the moment) and numerically. Thanks

Comment: Please read his: https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://luca-capriotti.net/pdfs/Finance/LSIS_final.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi7zrCnutDNAhWDOxoKHXrGAz0QFggdMAA&usg=AFQjCNEinXDLP7j8_Z8I12YJif7FhmheUw&sig2=UL4gWM9L1DUpRZESRIdyiw, especially around equations 21-22-23, but read everything first.

Comment: So he is talking about to generate $N_p'$ replications of the state variables $Z$ according to the original measure (I'm not sure what that exactly means for my Longstaff Schwartz case...). So if I got this right, this is to first run the original Longstaff-Schwartz algorithm $N_p'<<N_p$ times, (WITHOUT drift). Then use the SAME $Z$'s generated $N_p'$ times to generate the function $f_\theta(z)=\exp(\left(-\theta*Z_i-\frac{1}{2}\theta^2 t\right)^{1/2}\max \left(K-S(t),0\right)$, with starting values $x_0=Z_0$ and $y_0 = 0$, for EACH individual path?

Comment: The problem for my case is that I need the $Z_i$'s from every path, that are of different lengths due to optimal stopping time non-linear regression hard to implement :S

Comment: Also I dont think that it makes sense when they are drifting the Gaussian probability density to $N(\mu, \sigma^2$, since simulating from a GBM using euler sheme, the $Z_i$'s should be standard normal at each timestep. Thats the criteria when simulating a GBM no?

Comment: What language did you use to implement the least squares monte carlo method?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use :

$$f(t,S^\theta_t)=\max(K-S^\theta_t,0)\exp(-\theta W_t\color{red}{\mathbf{-}}\frac{1}{2}\theta^2t)$$

where $dS^\theta_t=(r+\sigma\theta)S^\theta_t dt + \sigma S^\theta_t dW_t$