# Finding optimal drift, importance sampling, least square monte carlo

Tags: monte-carlo, american-options, variance, payoff

I am working with Importance sampling for Least Squared monte carlo and have now problems understanding the implementation of the Robbins-Monro algorithm for finding the *optimal drift* for finding minimum variance of my estimate. The original problem formulation that is now answered is given [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27600/importance-sampling-for-pricing-options-with-longstaff-and-schwartz/).

The article I am following for Robbins-Monro algorithm is this [link](https://quanto.inria.fr/pdf_html/Arouna_doc/)

The problem i want to solve is to find a optimal drift $\theta^*$ by solving:

$H(\theta^*)=\min_{\theta}H(\theta)$

Where $H(\theta)=\mathbb{E}\left[ G^2(Z)e^{-\theta Z+\frac{1}{2}\theta^2}\right]$, the second moment of the payoff function $G(Z)=\max(K-S(t),0)$.
Indeed, we have: $\nabla H(\theta)=0$

Now following the Morris monro algorithm in the link, the general formulation of the stochastic algorithm is given in equation (10) and is given by:

$X_{n+1}=X_n-\gamma_{n+1}F(X_n,Z_{n+1})$

and going further to equation (15) we have the second moment (the gradient of $H(\theta)$) given by:

$h(\theta)=\nabla H(\theta)=\mathbb{E}\left[(\theta-Z)G^2(Z)e^{-\theta Z+\frac{1}{2}\theta^2}\right]$.

Now I wonder, since I don't know the second moment, how should I approximate it numerically in order to evaluate the algorithm? Given in the article, they don't really explain how the second moment is found?

Appreciate for help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$h(\theta)=\nabla H(\theta)=\mathbb{E}\left[(\theta-Z)G^2(Z)e^{-\theta Z+\frac{1}{2}\theta^2}\right]$

so just take a bunch of paths and evaluate
$$
(\theta-Z)G^2(Z)e^{-\theta Z+\frac{1}{2}\theta^2}
$$on them and take the average.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good paper which can help you.

https://www.rocq.inria.fr/mathfi/Premia/free-version/doc/premia-doc/pdf_html/mc_jourdainlelong_doc.pdf